# How to execute click() before mouseenter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem: I want to execute the `click()` event before the `mouseenter()` event. On mobile devices both work after clicking on an element, but I want `mouseenter()` to be executed *after* `click()`.

Here is my code:

```
    $(icon_disabled).click(function() {
      if($(disabled_list).hasClass("list-visible-sec")) {
        $(disabled_list).removeClass("list-visible-sec");
        $(this).removeClass("icons-visible");
      } else {
        $(disabled_list).addClass("list-visible-sec");
        $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
      }
    });

    $(icon_disabled).mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
      $(disabled_list).addClass("list-visible-sec");
    });
```

Comment: mouse enter logically should always run before click. on thing you can do if you really want this to happen could be put a delay and set click is true flag. You can then ignore the mouseenter event if click flag is true.

Comment: Add a call to the mouseenter at the end of the click, eg `$(this).trigger("mouseenter")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to trigger an event after another event you can trigger that event inside the callback of 1st event. Here I'm maintaining a counter to prevent multiple event to be activated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 let counter = 0;
 $('#test').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    if(counter === 0){
     $('#test').on('mouseenter', function(){
       console.log('mouseenter');  
       counter++;
     });
    }
    
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That because you want to trigger mouseenter after click right?? There is not direct way to do so as far I know

Comment: Adding a new event handler won't trigger the mouseenter event until you next mouseenter (as you're already over the element so won't "enter" it after the click).  Use `$(this).trigger("mouseenter")`